# NODEJS - Prevent duplicate keys from being added into an object array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function I am trying to use to not add duplicates (Later on will combine)

```
function arrayCombine(arrayOfValues, arrayOfValues2) {
    for (var arrName in arrayOfValues2) {
        if (arrayOfValues.indexOf(arrName)==-1) arrayOfValues.push([arrName, arrayOfValues2[arrName]]);
    }
    return arrayOfValues;
}
```

The arrays are lets say:

```
arrayOfValues
[
  [ 'test', 11 ],
  [ 'test2', 13 ],
  [ 'test3', 16 ],
]

arrayOfValues2
[
  [ 'test4', 12 ],
  [ 'test2', 25 ],
]
```

When I try to combine these, it does NOT remove the duplicate test2 here. It pushes it anyways.

This does not occur if the number does not exist so I assume when I'm checking for INDEXOF, there has to be a way to check for only the named value and not the numbered value too. What I mean is:

```
function arrayCombine(arrayOfValues, arrayOfValues2) {
    for (var arrName in arrayOfValues2) {
        if (arrayOfValues.indexOf(arrName)==-1) arrayOfValues.push(arrName);
    }
    return arrayOfValues;
}
```

Did work originally.

How can I have it only 'check' the name? In the future I will also combine but for now I just want to make sure no duplicate names get added.

Comment: You're playing fast and loose with the word 'key' here. What you have are values and arrays of values and arrays of arrays of values.

Comment: use `[].find()` instead of `[].indexOf()`.

Comment: Ah thanks both. Yeah makes sense sorry!

Comment: Are you trying to add the values of identical "keys", or push the values into an array?

Comment: The idea is to add non existing names into the array, and add up it if its a duplicate.

The array itself is passed down from a API so I'm trying to mostly do it from how it's given right now to me.

The above final array would be:

[
  [ 'test', 11 ],
  [ 'test2', 38 ],
  [ 'test3', 16 ],
  [ 'test4', 12 ],
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since objects only allow unique keys it may be simpler to use one to collate your data from both arrays. By [concatenating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the arrays, and then [reducing over them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create an object, you can add/combine each nested arrays values as you see fit. Then, to get an array back from the function use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) on the object.

```js
const arr1=[["test",11],["test2",13],["test3",16]],arr2=[["test4",12],["test2",25]];

// Accepts the arrays
function merge(arr1, arr2) {

  // Concatentate the arrays, and reduce over that array
  const obj = arr1.concat(arr2).reduce((acc, c) => {

    // Destructure the "key" and "value" from the
    // nested array
    const [ key, value ] = c;

    // If the "key" doesn't exist on the object
    // create it and assign an array to it, setting
    // the second element to zero
    acc[key] ??= [ key, 0 ];

    // Increment that element with the value
    acc[key][1] += value;

    // Return the accumulator for the next iteration
    return acc;

  }, {});

  // Finally return only the values of the object
  // which will be an array of arrays
  return Object.values(obj);

}

console.log(merge(arr1, arr2));
```

Additional documentation

- [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)